# Extract all the files with name containing a keyword

Tags: linux, move, file-management

I have thousands of html file in a directory. I wanna extract files that contain Chennai in the file name and put it into another folder. I am sure it is possible. I am not close enough to copy the files to another folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use globbing:

```
mv *Chennai* target/
```

If the file names might start with a dot, use

```
mv .*Chennai* *Chennai* target/
```

Comment: `cp` makes copies, `mv` moves. In this case, you can use the one you like more with the same syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
find directory_with_htmls -type f -name "*Chennai*.html" -exec cp {} some_other_folder \;
```

This would copy html files in the `directory_with_htmls` directory containing `Chennai` in the name to the directory `some_other_folder`.

Comment: Is it case sensitive? I mean the keyword alone?

Comment: Yes.  In order to make it case-insensitive, say `-iname` instead of `-name` in the above command line.

Comment: I am getting missing argument  to '-exec'

Comment: It quiet dint work. Only one file got copied out of thousand. File names are quiet improper. 

3BHK_flats_inCoimbatore.html__201308260608_ , 

buy_land_incoimbatore.html__201308190443_, Residential_Land_inCoimbatore.html__201308040550_ and so on

Comment: Your file names don't end in HTML which is contrary to what you'd said.  Remove `.html` from the pattern in the command.  Try `find directory_with_htmls -type f -iname "*Chennai*" -exec cp {} some_other_folder \;`

Comment: Opps. Sorry for not mentioning any files.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37632/discussion-between-venky-and-devnull)